# SQL Server data type to Oracle - Numeric (13, 12)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I could not find any help with this. I'm converting SQL Server tables to Oracle. I see this column definition in SQL Server and I'm not sure how to correctly convert this to an Oracle datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Some_Table]
(
      ....
      [ColumnName] [numeric](13, 12) NULL,
      ...
)
```

I understand this is number in Oracle but how to correctly translate (13,12)? Need a little help please. Thank you all.

Comment: if you use SQL Developer, it can capture and convert your SQL Server objects for you. We take NUMERIC to NUMBER fwiw

Comment: SQL Server version?

Comment: There is no SQL Server version. All I get is files. 
And no, not using SQL Developer to convert. Thank you.

Comment: @Art understood, but if you did, it'd be a lot easier.

Comment: I need more help with indexes and later with triggers. I posted new index question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general:

`NUMBER(13,12)` <=> `NUMERIC(13,12)`/`DECIMAL(13,12)`

From [Migrating-Oracle-to-SQL-Server-2014-and-Azure-SQL-DB.pdf](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/A/FCA37580-53F5-46DB-A981-E08018661F09/Migrating-Oracle-to-SQL-Server-2014-and-Azure-SQL-DB.pdf)

> **By default, SSMA maps NUMBER(< precision>, < scale>) to numeric(< precision>,
>   < scale>)** and NUMBER(< precision>) to numeric(< precision>). NUMBER becomes
>   float(53), which has the maximum precision from SQL Server floating-point numbers.

Comment: Thank you. I have never seen such number scales in Oracle and was confused a bit. Still does not make much sense to me but I will have to work with this. More questions about triggers and index conversions to follow shortly. Thanks again.